# sed: file skripta.txt line 1: unknown option to `s'

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I try to use:

```
sed -e 's/miza/stol/g' datoteka1.txt | sed -e '/klop/d' | sed -e '/^$/d' | sed -e 's/janez/Janez/g'
```

in a file named skripta.txt with "sed -f skripta.txt > datoteka2.txt" to save it in another file and I get this error mentioned in title.

If I run this code seperately it works just fine.

What is wrong here???

Comment: replacing / with something else doesn't even work like said on the internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me get this straight:

You have a file called `skripta.txt` that contains only this line:

```
sed -e 's/miza/stol/g' datoteka1.txt | sed -e '/klop/d' | sed -e '/^$/d' | sed -e 's/janez/Janez/g'
```

And you try to run it with

```
$ sed -f skripta.txt
```

Is that correct?

The error is not surprising then, because it expects just the `sed` commands, not a call to `sed` itself, inside the script file.

It interprets the initial `s` of the first `sed` as 'search and replace', but the following syntax `ed` doesn't match.

You can either change the `skripta.txt` into a shell script: (You could also change it's name into `skripta.sh`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sed -e 's/miza/stol/g' datoteka1.txt | sed -e '/klop/d' | sed -e '/^$/d' | sed -e 's/janez/Janez/g'
```

change it's mode to executable:

```
$ chmod u+x skripta.sh
```

Then you can just call it:

```
$ ./skripta.sh
```

Or you can turn it into a `sed` script by removing all the `seds`:

```
s/miza/stol/g
/klop/d
/^$/d
s/janez/Janez/g
```

Then you can run it with

```
$ sed -f skripta.txt < datoteka1.txt > datoteka2.txt
```

Comment: thanks, it does work. It seems like the professor gave wrong tips or I understood falsely

Answer (score 1):

This is a shell script that uses sed, not a sed script.

Run it with `bash skripta.txt > datoteka2.txt`

Comment: I'll have to use sed -f skripta.txt > datoteka2.txt because it is said in instructions for exercise.

Comment: Technically, he wants the output into `datoteka2.txt`, not `1`.